# Why don't set methods in Scala enforce comparable types?

Tags: scala

Consider the following example

```
val strings = Seq("foo", "bar")
val numbers = Seq(1,2,3)
strings.diff(numbers)
```

This is valid code (and results in an empty list), but why isn't scala picking up that we are comparing sets of different types?

There seems to be a type bound `B >: A` defined for `intersect`, `diff` and `union` but somehow it does not cause the compiler to reject my example as invalid.

Is there a type-strict/safe way of to do set operations in scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `Seq` is [covariant type(`+A`)](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html)

If you want to `diff` with `stricted` type, you can try it by:

```
strings.diff[String](numbers)
```

Comment: What is the motivation for not enforcing this strictness in standard library? Naively I'd assume set operations to just make sense for entities that at least share some trait (ie. have a common super-class/type)

Comment: @HolgerBrandl such as: Seq("foo", 1, 2, 3)

Comment: @HolgerBrandl Indeed, they share Any. If you look at the result type of strings.diff(numbers) it should be Any.

Comment: @chengpohi Thanks, indeed that's possible. However it never occurred to me to mix objects of different types in a collection since it somehow contradicts with my idea of typed programming.

Answer (score 4):

Even if I appreciate chengpohi's answer, it requires additional typing/thought, so I now use strict versions (continuing my example from the question):

```
implicit class StrictSetOps[T](someSeq: Seq[T]) {

  def strictDiff(that: Seq[T]) = {
    someSeq.diff(that)
  }

  def strictUnion(that: Seq[T]) = {
    someSeq.union(that)
  }

  def strictIntersect(that: Seq[T]) = {
    someSeq.intersect(that)
  }
}


// rejected by compiler
strings.strictDiff(numbers)


// compiler and the lazy developer are happy
val otherStrings = Seq("foo", "bar")
strings.strictDiff(otherStrings)
```